# Extract Country of fetched Tweets

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets, country-codes

I fetched Tweets and save it into csv by using tweepy. I want to extract country. I used `tweet.author.location` for extracting location. It gave me location like(city,state,country etc). I want to extract only country of the user. Is there any method for extracting country of the user by using tweepy.?

It would be great help for me.

Thank You !

Comment: Can you show the response you get here?

Comment: Yes, Sure. While I try to extract location by using `tweet.author.location` I will get output like this.."Bengaluru, India, Near Durga Mandir Babubasa, Debidanga, Champasari, Siliguri - 734 003, West Bengal, Tulungagung, Jawa Timur, Berkeley, CA etc." I want to extract only country.

Comment: Does the solution by @alice help? Or should I look into how to solve it?

Comment: Nope not worked. It gave me "Attribute Error". I read documentation of Twitter but not get my output.

Comment: It will give me "Attribute Error" like :- "User" has no attribute named "derived".

Comment: See if my solution is workable. It may be costly though. You'll have to save the country if you don't want it to be processed again and again

Answer (score 0):

If you fetch `tweet.author.derived.locations.country`, you should be able to get the country when it is available.

Here is the doc of `User` object: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/data-dictionary/overview/user-object.html

Comment: Nope not worked. It gave me "Attribute Error". I read documentation of Twitter but not get my output.

Comment: It will give me "Attribute Error" like :- "User" has no attribute named "derived".

Comment: Unfortunately, the `derived` values are only available in Twitter's Enterprise (commercial) APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is the perfect use case for `pycountry` package.

```
import pycountry
text = "Bengaluru, India, Near Durga Mandir Babubasa, Debidanga, Champasari, Siliguri"

for country in pycountry.countries:
    if country.name in text:
        print(country.name)
```

This code is just from the top of my head, may be a costly affair. 
Worth a try I guess.

Comment: Already done with pycountry. This works fine with whole country name is present in text. It not supporting abbreviations.

Comment: For abbreviations, you can use an already built dictionary maybe?